# URLDownloadToFile - XLSB file missing in downloaded Zip file from SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am using the code below to download a Zip file from HTTPS Sharepoint. I have checked on SharePoint that zip file is only containing XLSB file.

The size of the downloaded file is always 14KB whereas the actual Zip file size on SharePoint is 15MB. Even I can't open the Zip file. Coding is getting successfully run every time and not getting any error. However not getting appropriate results.

Can Someone please help me in this.

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
"URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr

#Else
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
"URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
 szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

#End If

Sub download_file()
Dim downloadStatus As Variant
Dim url As String
Dim destinationFile_local As String

url = "https://my.sharepoint.com/WW__Reporting/Shared%20Documents/Customer%20Reports/data%20Analysis/Data Analysis (Apr 11-17).zip"
destinationFile_local = "C:\Work\New folder\demand.zip"

downloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, destinationFile_local, 0, 0)

If downloadStatus = 0 Then
MsgBox "Downloaded Succcessfully!"
Else
MsgBox "Download failed"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably Windows or your AV deleting the file contents as potentially dangerous.

Comment: When you download a macro enabled file from the internet, you have to go to the file properties and "unblock" it first as a security measure. You can also unblock the ZIP file and it will unblock the files inside of it. https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/16545d1485950687-unblock-file-windows-10-a-unblock_file_in_properties-1.png?s=1bb29020b1a9919e802dec269baa58e0

Comment: @CharlesWilliams no,when I am downloading that file manually then it's getting downloaded properly and even XLSB file is also getting opened.

Comment: @braX XLSB file is working fine with out any issue when downloading the zip file manually. I tried to download PPT (available on sharepoint) as well by using same coding however facing same issue . File size is showing 4KB post downloading.

Comment: Your URL has a mix of %20 and spaces. I don't know if it makes a difference but replacing the spaces with %20 may help